# 3D surface of xts object

Tags: r, plot, 3d, xts

I would like to plot a 3D surface of an xts matrix where the number of rows is different than the number of columns. I have dates in the rows and numbers in the column headers, similar to the data below:

```
                    0       0.01       0.02       0.03       0.04       0.05
2003-01-31 0.07929216 0.07918058 0.07906927 0.07895823 0.07884747 0.07873699
2003-02-28 0.07963355 0.07951447 0.07939571 0.07927726 0.07915912 0.07904131
2003-03-30 0.07695306 0.07682813 0.07670350 0.07657918 0.07645517 0.07633147
2003-04-29 0.07998395 0.07986708 0.07975052 0.07963428 0.07951837 0.07940278
2003-05-30 0.08174700 0.08164435 0.08154198 0.08143989 0.08133809 0.08123658
2003-06-29 0.08144634 0.08134376 0.08124146 0.08113945 0.08103774 0.08093631
```

Is there a convenient way / package to do this without having to splice the data too much?

Comment: Thks this was really useful to me